# Solving linear and non-linear regression for vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, regression

I have a problem in the form Ab = c, where A is the unknown, a M x M matrix, and b is a M x 1 vector and c is a M x 1 vector. I have many samples of b and c (overdetermined problem) and I want to find the "best" A. Any suggestions of libraries that can easily solve this regression?

What about a non-linear but polynomial model? That is, some equation in the form:

[c_0 c_1 ... c_M ] = [1 b_0 b_1 ... b_M ... b_0^k b_1^k .. b_M^k ] A

Where k is the polynomial order, A is now a M x k matrix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197623/least-squares-regression-in-c-c

Comment: Polynomials have a nasty accuracy.

Comment: You will need to regularize when having problems with overfitting. Furthermore you probably do not want to model linear regression yourself; rather use a neural network or SVM. Anyway, Boost.UBLAS is pretty handy for implementing machine learning algorithms.

Comment: As far as I can see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197623/least-squares-regression-in-c-c main answer is to use LAPACK, but xGELS does not seem to solve Ab=c for multiple samples. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good solution: DLIB solves this problem quite well. There is an example here: 
http://dlib.net/least_squares_ex.cpp.html

Note: if you need to use matrices, DLIB still requires data to be stored as vectors. That is, if you are solving Ab=c and A is a 3x3 matrix, parameter_vector in the example linked above has to be `typedef matrix<double,9,1> parameter_vector;` or it won't compile.